# How to calculate the excpected Number if ec primes were random?

Tags: number-theory, statistics

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$, where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

The Vector containing all the numbers n leading to a prime or probable prime Is:

[2,3,4,7,8,12,19,22,36,46,51,67,79,215,359,394,451,1323,2131,3336,3371,6231,19179,39699,51456,56238,69660,75894,79798,92020,174968,176006,181015,285019,331259,360787,366770,541456]

I dont know if there are other ec probable primes between n=400000 and n=541456 maybe there could be one or two.
The thing that strikes me Is the abundance of multiples of $43$ in the vector,infact there are four n's (215,69660,92020,541456) out of 38 which are multiple of $43$.
If the primes of this type were random, how many n's leading to a prime would be excpected multiple of $43$ out of 38 n's leading to a prime? How to calculate the excpected Number of multiple of $43$?

Comment: The sample set is far too small to be meaningful.  Since $38$ is roughly equal to $43$, you'd expect just $1$ (to do it exactly, it's $\frac {38}{43}$), but, again, with samples this small and no prior rules set on what measurements you are will be taking, there's no apparent meaning here.

Comment: More precisely, using the binomial distribution (assuming independence of the values) you get just under a $1\%$ chance of observing exactly $4$ (and $1.15\%$ chance of seeing more than $3$), so if you ran $100$ tests with comparable probability you'd expect to observe such a phenomenon.

Comment: If you generates randomly a list of number, the proportion of multiples of 43 should be 1/43. 4 in 38 is more than expected, but 38 is to small to build some conjectures. Example, in your list, only 2, 12 and 22 ends with digit 2, is it normal, or strange ?

Comment: I only see $36$ numbers there.  Are $25$ or $29$ special because they are not factors of your sequence so far?  I doubt it, and similarly with $43$.

Comment: @Henry yes you are right I forgot 8 and 3336, now I corrected